# Is it true R vectors cannot hold NULL values?

Tags: r

In preparation to upload a data frame into postgres, I'd like to replace all blanks(i.e., "") and NA values with NULL.  The reason for this is, is that postgres will reject all integer type variable observations that are blank or NA.  After reading [THIS](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-na-vs-null/) article, I'm now under the impression that R vectors cannot hold NULL.  If that is true, then I shouldn't be able to convert blank and NA values in the data frame below to NULL.  Do I understand this correctly?

```
#Create data frame
sex = c(NA, 1, 0, "") 
age = c(23, 40, 16, NA) 
weight = c(156, 134, "", 190)
df = data.frame(sex,age,weight)
```

Comment: A SQL NULL value maps to NA in R. Postgres is rejecting the NAs probably because your table definition doesn't allow NULLs in those columns. Fix your table definition and the problem will go away.

Comment: In *atomic* vectors, NULL is removed.  A data frame is a list of atomic vectors (generally).  So NULL values are not allowed in data frames either.

Comment: Note also that vectors contain values of a _single_ type -- if you're using `""` as an element then all of the elements will be of type `character`.

Comment: this is what I thought, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I added `vectors` to the title because R can certainly hold `NULL` values...  in lists: `list(a = NULL, b = 2, c = NULL)` but not in vectors.

Comment: got it, thanks @JonathanCarroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#NULL-object

However, R can certainly hold `NULL` values... in `list`s:

```
list(a = NULL, b = 2, c = NULL)
#> $a
#> NULL
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $c
#> NULL
```

but not in `vector`s.